# Radar chart - show values near vertices in chart.js

Tags: chart.js

my question is if it's possible to disable radar chart vertices tooltips and instead of that always show values near vertices? I've tried to search it in documentation, but without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've found this awesome chart.js plugin: https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels